# getting exception in working process in gunicorn with django (on digitalocean)

Tags: django, ubuntu, deployment, gunicorn, digital-ocean

having trouble deploying django project with gunicorn and ningix on digital ocean. I have already created the droplet and am following the steps as mentioned in their official step by step guide but am stuck with these errors

This is the error im getting when i run this `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 wsgi:app`

```
[2023-06-13 11:58:41 +0000] [68713] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2023-06-13 11:58:41 +0000] [68713] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (68713)
[2023-06-13 11:58:41 +0000] [68713] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2023-06-13 11:58:41 +0000] [68714] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 68714
[2023-06-13 11:58:41 +0000] [68714] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
    mod = importlib.import_module(module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wsgi'
[2023-06-13 11:58:41 +0000] [68714] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 68714)
[2023-06-13 11:58:41 +0000] [68713] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2023-06-13 11:58:41 +0000] [68713] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
root@SnoffleSys:/home/mridul/djangoprojectdir# file /run/gunicorn.sock
/run/gunicorn.sock: socket
root@SnoffleSys:/home/mridul/djangoprojectdir# sudo journalctl -u gunicorn.socket
Jun 13 08:23:31 SnoffleSys systemd[1]: Listening on gunicorn socket.
Jun 13 08:26:56 SnoffleSys systemd[1]: gunicorn.socket: Failed with result 'service-start-limit-hit'.
Jun 13 08:27:09 SnoffleSys systemd[1]: Listening on gunicorn socket.
root@SnoffleSys:/home/mridul/djangoprojectdir# sudo systemctl status gunicorn
× gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2023-06-13 09:53:07 UTC; 2h 9min ago
   Duration: 4ms
TriggeredBy: ● gunicorn.socket
   Main PID: 66337 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
        CPU: 2ms

Jun 13 09:53:07 SnoffleSys systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
Jun 13 09:53:07 SnoffleSys systemd[66337]: gunicorn.service: Failed to locate executable /home/mridul/djangoprojectdir/djangoprojectenv/bin>
Jun 13 09:53:07 SnoffleSys systemd[66337]: gunicorn.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /home/mridul/djangoprojectdir/djangoprojectenv/bi>
Jun 13 09:53:07 SnoffleSys systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Jun 13 09:53:07 SnoffleSys systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

this is my gunicorn.service file

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=mridul
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/mridul/djangoprojectdir
ExecStart=/home/mridul/djangoprojectdir/djangoprojectenv/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          Snoffle_tech.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Im trying to upload my django project on digital ocean and following this blog [text](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-20-04),to upload it but midway im getting this problem.

```
root@SnoffleSys:/home/mridul/djangoprojectdir# sudo systemctl start gunicorn.socket
root@SnoffleSys:/home/mridul/djangoprojectdir# sudo systemctl enable gunicorn.socket
root@SnoffleSys:/home/mridul/djangoprojectdir# sudo systemctl status gunicorn.socket
● gunicorn.socket - gunicorn socket
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (listening) since Tue 2023-06-13 08:27:09 UTC; 3h 26min ago (and it should be running not listening)
      Until: Tue 2023-06-13 08:27:09 UTC; 3h 26min ago
   Triggers: ● gunicorn.service (and the dot is red it is supposed to be be green)
     Listen: /run/gunicorn.sock (Stream)
     CGroup: /system.slice/gunicorn.socket

Jun 13 08:27:09 SnoffleSys systemd[1]: Listening on gunicorn socket.
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Verify the Gunicorn executable path: Ensure that the path specified in the ExecStart directive of your gunicorn.service file is correct. Double-check that the virtual environment path /home/mridul/djangoprojectdir/djangoprojectenv and the Gunicorn executable gunicorn exist in that location.

2.Test Gunicorn directly: Try running Gunicorn manually in the terminal to see if you encounter any errors. Navigate to your project directory (/home/mridul/djangoprojectdir) and activate the virtual environment (source djangoprojectenv/bin/activate). Then run the Gunicorn command specified in the ExecStart directive of the gunicorn.service file directly:

```
/home/mridul/djangoprojectdir/djangoprojectenv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock Snoffle_tech.wsgi:application
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort 
1. the Gunicorn file is actually present in the specified directory of virtual environment path /home/mridul/djangoprojectdir/djangoprojectenv

2. upon running the command directly it gives the error
'''
(djangoprojectenv) root@SnoffleSys:/# /home/mridul/djangoprojectdir/djangoprojectenv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock Snoffle_tech.wsgi:application
-bash: /home/mridul/djangoprojectdir/djangoprojectenv/bin/gunicorn: cannot execute: required file not found
'''
although the file is present in the directory for sure